# Why View contains children in Android when using DDMS Dump View

Tags: android, ddms

I am new to android, and it seems only viewgroup can be parent of some View, but when I use DDMS to dump view hierarchy of an app, I find there is a View containing some children. Could anyone please explain this to me? Please see the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To investigate on that issue I created a custom ViewGroup that does nothing:

```
private static class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
  public MyViewGroup(Context _context) { super(_context); }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean _changed, int _l, int _t, int _r, int _b)
  { /* nothing... */ }
}
```

and added it to the current content view of an activity:

```
ViewGroup foo = (ViewGroup)
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
foo.addView(new MyViewGroup(this));
```

The hierarchy viewer of eclipse shows it labeled as a 'View' too.

Furthermore I looked at the Node details of another 'View' with Children and was able to see a resource-id.
In my case it had the value `android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout` and I could find that resource-id to be used in an XML-layout for a `android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout` component.
It's implementation is in the support library and truely extends Framelayout.

I think this issue is simply the hierarchy viewer only supporting labels for standard view components.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I think that any ViewGroup that is not one of the ViewGroup-implementations provided by Android will be shown as View, maybe to hide the name of your custom ViewGroups from others. So it is basically a privacy thing for the developers